# 2dnav_pr2 failed on 2DNavigationStackDemoWithSimple2DesksWorld

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In doc page: http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/2DNavigationStackDemoWithSimple2DesksWorld

2dnav_pr2 package doesn't exist,so I can't execute

```
 roslaunch 2dnav_pr2 rviz_move_base.launch
```

and

```
 roslaunch rviz/rviz_move_base.launch
```

How to solve it?Is there any latest docs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10570/2dnav_pr2-failed-on-2dnavigationstackdemowithsimple2desksworld/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This tutorial is just outdated (last edit in January 2010). The launch files you are mentioning are not present anymore but I guess they would just start up rviz for visualizing data from navigation. Have a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack) for more infos on rviz and the navigation stack.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-07-14**:
I think it is a lot of work to keep all tutorials up-to-date so some might always be outdated. If you find problems, you can file a ticket. Since it is a wiki page, you can also edit the tutorial yourself, but I would only do that if I'm totally sure about what I'm doing ;)

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-14**:
Thank you~Is there anyone who will maintain the docs always to be latest?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

2dnav_pr2 contents were migrated to pr2_navigation_global, wiki updated.  thanks for reporting.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2